# Помогите решить ошибку в коде

Tags: python, pyqt5

При выводе, в консоли выходит ошибка:

```
     result = 100 - (second_mass / (first_mass / 100))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Вот сам код:

```
def bp():
    first_mass = ui.lineEdit.text()
    second_mass = ui.lineEdit_2.text()

    result = 100 - (second_mass / (first_mass / 100))

    ui.label.setText("%.2f" % + {result} + ' %')

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)
```

Помогите решить пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first_mass` и `second_mass` — это строки. Преобразуйте их в числа.

***Пример:***

```py
first_mass = float(ui.lineEdit.text())
second_mass = float(ui.lineEdit_2.text())

result = 100 - (second_mass / (first_mass / 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Преобразуйте строки `first_mass` и другую в числа с помощью `int()`